# Why is C# Marshalling Strings not Working with C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I am having issues passing strings to a certain function in my external DLL. I would post an actual code snippet but it's kind of messy and might be hard to read. The following snippets are what my personal code boils down to.

**C# File (UNICODE)**

```cs
[DllImport("InjectDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern ulong FindProgramProcessId(string procName);
[DllImport("InjectDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern bool InjectIntoProcess(ulong procId, string Dll);
string ProcName = "random_test_game.exe";
string DllPath = @"C:\ProgramData\Hack\File.dll";
ulong procId = FindProgramProcessId(ProcName);
bool Injected = InjectIntoProcess(procId, DllPath);
```

**C++ File (ANSI)**

```cpp
DllExport DWORD FindProgramProcessId(const char* procName)
{
    ...
}
DllExport bool InjectIntoProcess(DWORD procId, const char* Dll)
{
    if (Dll == nullptr)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "DLL", "EMPTY", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

**C++ Header File**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <string>
#ifdef EXPORT
#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DllExport __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
extern "C" DllExport DWORD FindProgramProcessId(const char* procName);
extern "C" DllExport bool InjectIntoProcess(DWORD procId, const char* Dll);
```

Referencing the snippets, the issue arising is that FindProgramProcessId will successfully pass a string, no problemo, but InjectIntoProcess will show `const char* Dll` as `nullptr` according to the "extra" code I put in that method.

Notice, I have tried passing an `IntPtr` in place of `string` and using `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`, and I still get the `Dll == nullptr` issue. It's breaking my code. More of the same info can be found here at my [GuidedHacking](https://guidedhacking.com/threads/cant-pass-c-string-to-c-dll-for-loader.12989/) thread.

Comment: `DWORD` is 32 bits, `ulong` is 64 bits. That might be your problem. Try declaring `procId` as `uint` instead.

Comment: ok thanks will try that

Comment: Thanks that worked! You can go ahead and simply add an answer and I'll mark it. I didn't think that the first argument could be the problem. `DWORD` is an `unsigned long` and `ulong` is an `unsigned long`. My bad, really appreciate your help! <333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Win32 `DWORD` is a 32 bit integer, but the C# `ulong` is a 64 bit integer. The confusion stems from the fact that `DWORD` is an alias for `unsigned long`, but the C++ `long` isn't necessarily 64 bits (in fact, in MSVC, it's 32 bits; `unsigned long long` is the 64 bit unsigned integer).

Since you're using the cdecl calling convention, the caller is responsible for cleaning the stack (so no crash occurs), and arguments are passed right-to-left (so `Dll` ends up pointing somewhere in the middle of the value passed to `procId`, which probably contains zeroes). Or at least that's my guess, since we're in undefined behavior territory here.

You should declare the return value of `FindProgramProcessId` and the `procId` parameter of `InjectIntoProcess` as `uint` instead.